# Usage of .fadeIn() and .fadeOut()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) { 
        $('#logoheader').css("opacity", 1);
    }
    else{
        $('#logoheader').css("opacity", 0);
    }
});
```

This allows me to let a logo appear after I scroll past a banner. However, this is a cold hard appearance. I would like to make this a little more smooth thus I tried to use `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` however I could not get this to work. Is there a quick and easy way to do this? Note, due to compatibility issues I can not use CSS animations.

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't get this to work"? Replacing the .css functions with .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() should work just fine, if you don't want to use CSS transformations.

Comment: replace `.css` for `.animate` ?

Comment: please post your css and html code snipets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) { 
        $('#logoheader').fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else{
        $('#logoheader').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

CSS(added CSS is only to show functionality, `display:none;` is the only one you will actually need):

```
#logoheader {
    display:none;
    height:100px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99y7Q/)

Comment: Perfect, the problem was a conflict in the CSS. Many thanks! (will accept answer in a few minutes)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more smooth, try using: `.fadeIn('slow')` or `.fadeIn('medium')`.

It works with `.fadeOut()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a duration to the show method in jquery

```
$('#logoheader').show('slow');
```

more details on: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

fadeIn() / fadeOut() sets the elements to display:none after outfading. If you wan't to fade in an element which hasn't display none the function fails. A workaround would be to .hide() the element before fadeIn(), but more propper way is to set display:none initially in CSS

workaround:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#logoheader').hide(); //same as display:none in css
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) { 
        $('#logoheader').fadeIn();
    }
    else{
        $('#logoheader').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: The workaround is going to look terrible though, because then anytime the page is scrolled, if it's already shown, it's going to blink out and fade back in. Setting it once in CSS is much better.

Comment: ah saw what you mean. I made an edit to make it look nicer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) { 
        $('#logoheader').fadeIn();
    }
    else{
        $('#logoheader').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Works as noted, the issue is in your css you have to set `#logoheader` to `display: none` rather than `opacity: 0`

Answer (score 0):

This work just fine http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/E9ZLm/1/ probably you forgot to remove the opacity:0; in your css.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) { 
        $('#logoheader').fadeIn();
    }
    else{
        $('#logoheader').fadeOut();;
    }
});
```

The **CSS**

```
.fixedheight{
    height:800px;
    width:100%;
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
}
#logoheader{
    position:absolute;
    top:250px;
    left:0;
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    **display:none;**
}
```

note the display:none;

Answer (score 0):

Improved @APAD1 solution:

```
var $target = $('#logoheader'); // declare it only one time

// it's a good idea check if the $target is already visible before force to show
// something that is already shown (and vice versa)

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= 250 && !$target.is(':visible') ) { 
        $target.fadeIn('slow');
    }
    else if( $(window).scrollTop() < 250 && $target.is(':visible') ){
        $target.fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

[check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/99y7Q/2/)

Comment: remember to hide `$target` after declaring it if you won't use css

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same code and just use CSS transition

```
#logoheader{
   transition:opacity 1s ease;
   -moz-transition:opacity 1s ease; 
   -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease; 
   -o-transition:opacity 1s ease; 
   -ms-transition:opacity 1s ease; 
}
```

thats it..

http://jsfiddle.net/vjSHL/